# So God may be glorified as we serve

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Help. Can anyone translate this to Latin?

"So God may be glorified as we serve."

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you provide a bit more context? Is it implied that something has to be done (so glory may be given to God)? Is ecclesiastical Latin adequate? Would you prefer a quote with an approximate meaning over a literal translation, if available?

Answer (score 2):

“So God may be glorified” in itself is reminiscent of the motto of the Benedictine order: *Ut in omnibus glorificetur deus* (UIOGD, “So that God may be glorified in all things”), itself adapted from the Bible, [1 Peter 4:11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20peter%204%3A11&version=VULGATE) (where it says *honorificetur* = “may be honoured,” though).

Starting from that basic structure, I think the best way to put the “we” in there and still keep the sentence short and sweet is to convert it to the active mood (“so that we may glorify”). God takes on the accusative:

> Ut servientes glorificemus Deum.

*Servientes* simply means “serving” and modifies the subject “we,” so it perfectly captures “as we serve.”

Note: *Glorificare* is a typical Christian Latin vocable, which I think fits the occasion well. In classical Latin one would perhaps rather use *illustrare*.